# Amazon S3 buckets, limit the number of requests per day, limit of size

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

currently developing a "social network"-like website, I plan to use an Amazon S3 bucket to store users' profile pictures. Does anyone know whether there is an easy way to set :

- the maximum number of requests per day a bucket can accept
- the maximum size that the bucket can reach
- the maximum size a given picture must not exceed to be accepted

My fear being that a given user would upload such a big picture (or such a big number of pictures, or create such a high number of profiles) that my amazon S3 bill would skyrocket...

(I know that some 'a posteriori' alerts can be set, but I'm looking for a solution that would prevent this situation..)

Any help greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a configuration in the S3 to limit the upload requests per day or maximum size that bucket can reach.
If you are concerned by a large sized photo upload, why don't you simply do it on the front-end side? Using Web Files API, you can get the selected file size and alert the user that it exceeds the limitation.

Comment: I thought that using this (non-existing --thank you for the answer) native feature of amazon-s3 would be a more robust way to prevent a 'hacking' of this sort. I'm going to deal with it in the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

> the maximum number of requests per day a bucket can accept

S3 allows 3500 PUT/DELETE/POST requests per second per folder. So, say your s3 bucket is "pics" which has folders on the basis of date (yyyy/mm/dd).
So, for each of the paths pics/2020/01/01, pics/2020/01/02, pics/2020/01/03 and so on, you will have the above mentioned throughput available.

> the maximum size that the bucket can reach

Buckets have no upper size limit.

> the maximum size a given picture must not exceed to be accepted

S3 has a per object limitation of 5TB. Hence, the user cannot upload a pic of size greater than 5TB. Obviously, that's not the limit you were expecting.

To handle your custom limitations, custom code would have to be written.

May I suggest using AWS Lambda whenever an upload is triggered. The said Lambda can validate the size of the pic, can even compress it (to save on S3 storage cost) and upload to your S3 bucket.

Comment: I'm going to look at lambda AWS. By chance, do you know whether it could also set a maximum number of request per amazon user AIM ?

Comment: @user14437794 Lambda has a default limit of 1000 concurrent executions. That means, you can trigger only 1000 lambdas at 1 point in time. However, this is a soft limit and can be very easily increased by placing a request via your AWS account.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html